# Kafka adding SASL users dynamically without cluster restart

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

We want to add authentication to our kafka cluster by using SASL. As we see that we want to be able to frequently add users we are looking for at way to do this without having to perform a rolling restart.

What we have tried:

Using the Dynamic Broker Configuration interface, reconfiguring `listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.jaas.config` for all brokers.

The kafka brokers pick up on the change in zookeeper 
`[2019-01-11 11:08:23,403] INFO Processing override for entityPath: brokers/1 with config: Map(listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.jaas.config -> encryptedPassword:XXX,keyLength:128,cipherAlgorithm:AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,initializationVector:YYY,keyFactoryAlgorithm:PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512,salt:ZZZ,iterations:4096,passwordLength:270) (kafka.server.DynamicConfigManager)`

However new users are not able to connect until the broker is restarted.

Is it possible to add new users to the SASL JAAS configuration without restarting the Kafka cluster?

Comment: Which version of Kafka you are using?

Comment: @Steephen 2.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `plain` mechanism in `sasl_plaintext`,
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732233/5687237) you're not able to add a new user in a running cluster.

instead, you can switch to `SCRAM` mechanism and after that, you'll be able to create a user in running cluster with a command like this:

```
$ > bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=alice-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=alice-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name alice
```

However, you still need to keep JAAS config file but, you just pass it once when starting the server.

Here is a [useful link in Kafka document](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_scram) about using `SCRAM` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! We will be looking in that direction

Comment: I think you should remove the quotes from the config section after --add-config.

Comment: @M.Ismail based on the Kafka document link in the answer, it's necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to add tls to this?

Comment: Warning: --zookeeper is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Kafka.